# ng-hide="true" is not hiding the element

Tags: angular, ng-hide

I'm using Angular 11. Somehow I can't make this div disappear:
My simple `HTML` :

```
<div ng-hide="true">Test</div>
```

Result -> The Text Test still appears on my page.

Comment: use *ngIf or [hidden]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular2+ there is no directive with `ng-` format. This format is available only for `angular.js`. But you know there is almost equivalent directive in Angular2+.

For your question there are some ways to do the same behavior of `ng-hide`:

First one is: `[hidden]=true`:

```
<div [hidden]="true">…content..</div>
```

Second one is: `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf=”bolShow”>…content…</div>
```

Third one is style binding like this: `[style.visibility]`

```
<div [style.visibility]="bolShow ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">…content…</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-hide` and `ng-show`don't exist in Angular 2+ only in AngularJS.
I'm using

```
<div [hidden]="true">Text</div>
```

now.

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ng-show-and-ng-hide-in-angular